How to get an access token for FCM OAuth to send via Proxy which needs authentication?
I'm able to get accesstoken from GoogleCredential class via proxy server,but my proxy server needs authentication details to be given.I'm getting error as "Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required",as my proxy server requires authentication.I'm using google-api-client-1.23.0.jar,google-http-client-1.23.0.jar.
My problem is how can I get access token via a proxy authentication? below is the code snippet
HttpTransport httpTransport = null;         
                NetHttpTransport.Builder netHttpTransportBuilder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
                netHttpTransportBuilder.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(httpClient.getHostConfiguration().getProxyHost(), httpClient.getHostConfiguration().getProxyPort())));
                httpTransport = netHttpTransportBuilder.build();        
        
        
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = null;
        // Create Google Credential with proxy settings and scopes
         googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream(filePath), httpTransport, com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory())
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(arr));

